# Automatically create points based on algorithm

Tags: arcmap, point, arcgis-10.4, algorithm

I have a shapefile with points representing the sightings of different bird species on different dates (in ArcMap 10.4.1). I now have to create a new shapefile with points for bird territories. A territory point is drawn when two points (sightings) of the same species on different dates are not more than 100 Meters apart.

[image: screenshot of workspace]

Explanation of screenshot: The squares represent a single sighting of a bird (red, green and blue), The circle (black) represents a manually drawn territoty. The colors (red, blue and green) represent the date of a sighting (e. g. red = 13.04.2021). I am using select by attributes to illustrate sightings of the same species (hollow blue circle). When two sightings of the same specis on diffrent dates are not more than 100 meteres apart a territoy (black circle) is drawn between them (as you can see in the bottom of the picture).

Is there a way to create my territory-points automatically if they meet the given conditions, so I dont have to create the territories manually?

Comment: Edit your question to include an image showing your input data and desired output as its not clear where you want your territory point located?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your post to include a single, focused question?

Comment: What if you try one of the tools offered here: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-blog/concave-hulls-the-elusive-container/ba-p/902545 ?